# cygwin, компиляция сразу по всем подпапкам

Tags: java, cygwin

Всем добра! Нужно в cygwin (windows 7) запустить компиляцию всех *.java файлов во всех подпапках. То есть что-то вроде:

```
javac src/**/*.java
```

javac выдает "file not found"

Если такую же маску использовать с командой rm (rm src/**/*.java) , то пишет No such file or directory.
Как добиться в cygwin нужного результата? Есть альтернативный способ?

Answer (score 1):

Ну тогда напишите таким образом

```
find src -type f -name *.java -exec javac {} \;
```

(убедитесь, что запускаете в баше, а не в cmd)